# How to calculate average clustering when Graph is not connected?

Tags: networking

I try to use code:
'nx.average_clustering(G1)'

but it returns:
'NetworkXError: Graph is not connected.'

I want o know how to calculate average clustering when Graph is not connected. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution for this problem.
Reference Link:https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/networkx-discuss/mp5AEebIeKo
Code:

```
import pprint
import numpy
import networkx as nx
def average_clustering_for_all(G1):
    tempgraph1=G1.copy();
    if nx.is_connected(tempgraph1):
    # Normal case, the graph is connected
        average=nx.average_clustering(tempgraph1);
    else:
    # Try to see if the graph is not connected because of isolated nodes
        tempgraph1.remove_nodes_from(nx.isolates(tempgraph1));
        if nx.is_connected(tempgraph1):
        # Compute the graph average path without isolated nodes
            average=nx.average_clustering(tempgraph1);
        else:
            # Compute the average shortest path for each subgraph and mean it!
            subgraphs = nx.connected_component_subgraphs(tempgraph1)
            average=0;
            for sb in subgraphs:
                pprint.pprint(sb.degree());
                average+=nx.average_clustering(sb);
                if len(list(subgraphs)) == 0:
                     continue
                if len(list(subgraphs))!=0:
                    average/=(len(list(subgraphs)))
             return average;
 average_clustering_for_all(G1) code here
```